# Export p-values from reghdfe to Excel

Tags: excel, stata

I am trying to export p-values to Excel from the Stata *community-contributed* command `reghdfe`:

```
// get data
use "http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/nlswork.dta", clear
xtset idcode year

// run regression
reghdfe ttl_exp age not_smsa msp nev_mar, abs(idcode year) cluster(idcode)

// store numbers
local rmse = `e(rmse)'  

// export
putexcel A1 = (`rmse') using "export.xlsx" , modify // this works
```

How can I get the p-value of a given variable (say `msp`) exported to the same Excel document?

The `ereturn list` does not suggest any helpful info, `e(V)` contains only the covariance matrix.

Cross posted [on Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1489504-export-specific-regression-table-outputs-to-excel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
use "http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/nlswork.dta", clear
xtset idcode year

reghdfe ttl_exp age not_smsa msp nev_mar, abs(idcode year) cluster(idcode)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
     ttl_exp |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         age |   -.008044   .0618821    -0.13   0.897     -.129366    .1132781
    not_smsa |  -.1616256   .0812134    -1.99   0.047    -.3208472   -.0024039
         msp |   -.004893   .0634814    -0.08   0.939    -.1293505    .1195645
     nev_mar |    -.36351   .0955207    -3.81   0.000    -.5507816   -.1762384
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local pval = (2 * ttail(e(df_r), abs(_b[msp] / _se[msp]) ) )

display `pval'
.93856498

putexcel A1 = (`pval') using "export.xlsx", modify
```

Comment: very elegant solution, I was so cuaght up in figuring out where to find that information in Stata, that I did not even conceive of computing it myself using the other stored values. Very nice, thanks!